# UnitTesing from Visual Studio with admin rights

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

My program reads registry keys under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UpgradeCodes.
```

When I execute unit test from VS2010, the key can not be opened

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer
```

can be opened without any problems, but it has no subkeys.
When I execute my program, it works well.

I suppose there is a rights issue with units tests... Do you know, if it is possible to execute unit tests with admin rights?
I've tried already to start VS as Administrator and switched off UAC.

Comment: you should think to registry as a dependency, so you should abstract them and mock

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mocking the Registry - SystemWrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320650/mocking-the-registry-systemwrapper)

Answer (score 1):

You should think to registry as a system dependency, so you need to abstract theme in your design, then moq it to test.

Anyway this is a possible duplicate of:
[Mocking the Registry - SystemWrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320650/mocking-the-registry-systemwrapper)

Comment: Well, it looks very reasonably..., but the first problem i have with SystemWrapper is, that there is no enumeration. Or i didn't find how to enumerate sub keys.